# jquery id getting help

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to put  the id into the colorbox below this code nom works but the page with the link on it is

```
$("#recent_activity").load("activity.php?id="+id+"&random=" +unique_requestid());
```

thats how it calls the page  and the link is on that page.

```
var id = $.query.get('id');

$("a[href='write_comment.php?act=write&id="+id+"']").colorbox({width:"500", height:"350", iframe:true});
```

thank you

Comment: Just a note: That selector looks like it could easily become a maintenance problem. Perhaps you could give that link an id or class (with an added speed boost, especially if it's an Id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question entirely, but if all you're trying to do is set the id of an element, you can do so with the [attr(key, value) method](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue). For instance:

```
foo.attr('id', id);
```

Is this what you're trying to do?